# SQL ROUND() function with truncate takes 119.1 and returns 119.09

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, rounding, truncate

I have data for pounds and pence stored within concatenated strings (unfortunately no way around this) but can not guarantee 2 decimal places.

E.g. I may get a value of `119.109`, so this must translated to 2 decimal places with truncation, i.e. `119.10`, NOT `119.11`.

For this reason I am avoiding "CAST as Decimal" because I do not want to round. Instead I am using `ROUND(amount, 2, 1)` to force truncation at 2 decimal places.

This works for the most part but sometimes exhibits strange behaviour. For example, `119.10` outputs as `119.09`. This can be replicated as:

```
ROUND(CAST('119.10' AS varchar),2,1)
```

My target field is Decimal(19,4) (but the 3rd and 4th decimal places will always be 0, it is a finance system so always pounds and pence...).

I assume the problem is something to do with ROUNDing a varchar....but I don't know anyway around this without having to `CAST` and therefore introduce rounding that way?

What is happening here?

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Different products may behave differently...

Comment: Thanks for looking. I am using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind: trunc(x*100) /100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the way floating point numbers work, and the fact that your string number is implicitly converted to a floating point number before being rounded. In your test case:

```
ROUND(CAST('119.10' AS varchar),2,1)
```

You are implicitly converting `119.10` to float so that it can be passed to the `ROUND` function, 119.10 exactly cannot be stored as a float, proven by running the following:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(FLOAT, '119.10') AS DECIMAL(30, 20))
```

Which returns:

```
119.09999999999999000000
```

Therefore, when you round this with truncate you get 119.09.

For what it is worth, you should [always specify a length when converting to, or declaring a varchar](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Thanks for this, that makes sense. However if I explicitly convert to decimal then won't that introduce the rounding that I want to avoid?

Comment: Good point, couldn't you then just take the first two digits from the pence string? e.g. `Pounds + '.' + LEFT(Pence, 2)`

Comment: That could work! Having checked the data Im getting...unfortunately though I may sometimes get a value of "119" ...and therefore have to assume 0 pence....so perhaps have to check for a "." first?

Comment: Would there be any benefit in multiplying by 100, flooring the result, and then dividing by 100? or will there still be inherent cast rounding

Comment: If pence is its own varchar field, you could use `Pounds + '.' + RIGHT('00' + LEFT(Pence, 2))`, this will ensure that there are always at least 2 digits in the pence.

Comment: Thanks - I can't split my pounds and pence in the source data but I wrote a function to do that with SUBSTRING